# how do you make nature disappear from your mesh when you try to make it like glass?

Tags: transparency

I am following a tutorial on Youtube on how to make a donut and coffee cup on blender, When I lowered the transmission on the coffee cup to make it glass-like, a nature-like reflection was on the cup instead.

https://gm1.ggpht.com/Nxj5tZSjdpvk79q72M73tKROzByWwzni6vFmV9UtU_XU83IjvDWqfFegQOzrFKrmJTVS0hshXmj1lGQqLVIeZmopE3DhHuFssgD30RBBci2lHOw8WbC3LCKEgI8oJN5JT-Rmi7DSdxIXWzu8lpHpjct10SWq9414rJpHBSByz_4YDT8VWKzr48gX78w5S5WPABUdp94C__FVrS6STw5ugoSKCwcQFTfcvrbvG5Ybzifk9aHFW-BwwBcg1oKKpMHa_TCJwr2bBz-fF46LEtre1iZAWRBkXtWmYpp7JZreTZBvm-1D3WE5-SorPpRSD3_052mCrbxu5EOVWcRIH5w_DhlxnIvsbCLNYxDZVS7WrsbUWVih7WXl8ZiPOFOVsUjHFcxvRxVHT8o3YnAmitHAXvfue7JMOZxSSQSqA3dRZ2U96bQEgk1hUhCAg1doUvPRu-LvRPKVDm6GaPZ20tnL5jcBDaxTHDwrQ6HYUu_LSjUAuue3zRr8PKYSHa7H1c7Zvb6L_InXrlaMU0uLX40EnWqLuuvJITk_VRdq7HVljqVrv4MOAsxUAHuZj2V25Bn5C8iTmlaXVpqB5kKGJWCmOV1h6uUhqD7Afjo0udxsVYZ5mJ9ylhAi3cHuNLdCk1gLgrjKEdktNUoMsbonuC186_amFA9IEfMcaDclh--yiX0pBareI37zHtpoLXAixVXvH1djTF-QEhG_IeXve7SqLYAew970j9n-amwgjdtS=s0-l75-ft-l75-ft

Comment: Your URL results in a 403 (forbidden) error.  If you're trying to add your blend file, Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.

If you are trying to add an image, edit the answer and drag the image into it.

Comment: What's this crazy long link? It's doesn't work, just gives a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: You're probably seeing the reflection of the HDRI background image, but as @Marty Fouts says you'll have to upload the Blend file so that we can check.

Comment: I think you are in Material Preview mode. Press Z in the 3D viewport and select "Rendered" from the pie menu.